# CMake flags are pointing to the wrong Qt version

Tags: qt, cmake

Flags like QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY and QT_USE_FILE are returning the paths to an older version of Qt, even though I have `FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 4.8.2 REQUIRED)` at the top.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Is the correct qmake in your PATH?

Comment: Yes the qmake links to C:/Qt/4.8.2/bin/qmake.exe which is correct, however the flags I mentioned above seem to refer to my older Qt version (http://i.imgur.com/8Mj17.png)

Comment: Deleting build dir and configuring the project again might help.

Comment: Your build seems to mix debug libs (QtOpengld) and release libs (QtGui). That can only go wrong. Make sure all libraries linked together either use debug or release, but not a mix of them.

Answer (score 0):

Delete CMakeCache.txt in your build directory and generate again. Sometimes it's necessary to update CMakeCache.txt especially if you upgrade some sided library used by you in your project.

Comment: it doesn't help, cmake finds qt from miniconda in my case