# Linking against specific Qt library version number

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries, version

I am developing a Qt application that I need to distribute. I need to ensure that the distributed application links at runtime against Qt version 4.8.1, but my application binary always depends on Qt 4, which points to a different version on my machine.

I have installed on my machine both Qt 4.6.2 (default Qt version installed for my Linux distribution) and Qt 4.8.1 (the one I need for my application), both in /usr/lib. The ideal solution I am searching for is specifying somehow in my CMakeLists.txt that I need my binary needs a specific Qt version to work. I tried with

```
find_package(Qt4 4.8.1 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)
```

but my output for

```
ldd executableName
```

is still

```
libQtOpenGL.so.4 => /usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so.4
```

which points to the default (wrong) 4.6.2 Qt version. I would like to get if possible

```
libQtOpenGL.so.4.8.1 => /usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so.4.8.1
```

So my binary can run properly and the default Qt version installed remains untouched.

Thank you.

Comment: [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11934147/1387438), but without solution :(

Comment: I wouldn't install Qt manually to /usr/lib, especially not if you have another distro-managed Qt in there (actually, I'd never install anything manually to /usr/lib). If you want a specified Qt version, install it to a custom path and build against that.

Comment: I use a different path for building the application, but, what about runtime? Do you suggest to use also a different path and make use of rpath?

Comment: Yes, rpath is the way to go.